# Can I replace the relative adjective "where" with "that"?

Tags: relative-clauses, relative-adverbs

—Can you believe I had to pay 30 dollars for a haircut?

—You should try the barber’s **where** I go. It’s only 15.

In the above sentence, can I replace "where" with "that" or omit it?

Can I say "You should try the barber’s **that** I go" or You should try the barber’s I go?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you cannot simply replace *where* with a relative pronoun or ‘null relativizer’.

This is because *where* itself is not a relative pronoun—it does not ‘stand for’ a noun or NP—but a relative adverb: it stands for a locative, a preposition phrase. *Where* in your initial sentence does not represent ‘the place’ but ‘**to** the place’.

Consequently, when you replace *where* with a pronoun you must at the same restore the preposition which is ‘embedded’ in its sense:

> You should try the barber’s **that** I go **to** *OR*
>   You should try the barber’s I go **to** *OR*
>   You should try the barber’s **which** I go **to** *OR*
>   You should try the barber’s **to which** I go.

Comment: What does "NP" mean? "noun phrase"?  Can you give me an example? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @April An NP is a constituent which acts as a noun: it may be a noun with its modifiers (a noun phrase), but it may also be a clause, as in "I thought that you were home" - *that you were home* is an NP, the direct object of *thought*.